# Cannot reverse a multidimensional array

Tags: php

I have an array with this structure:

```
[
    {
        "id": "2644688"
    },
    {
        "id": "2644689"
    }
]
```

I'm trying to reverse it using `array_reverse`:

```
$reversed = array_reverse($result, true);
return $response->withJson($reversed);
```

but I get:

```
{
 "0": {
       "id": "2644688"
 },
 "1": {
       "id": "2644689"
 }
}
```

the order is the same, the function `array_reverse` just added the numerical indexes, I did something wrong?

Comment: This is how your array is encoded to json.

Comment: @u_mulder so I should deserialize it first?

Comment: json_encode wont preserve order

Comment: I've tried the same but result is as you want it not as you showed here.

Comment: @LovepreetSingh you get the revert?

Comment: This is what I got: `{"1":{"id":"2644689"},"0":{"id":"2644688"}}`

Comment: @LovepreetSingh are you sure? I get the same output wrote in question

Comment: but wait, I didn't used json_encode, why my question was marked as json_encode duplicate?

Comment: The code I've tried: `$array = json_decode($json, true);
print_r(json_encode(array_reverse($array)));`.

Comment: @LovepreetSingh but you have passed a json, I have an array first

Comment: The first array you have given is also in form of json.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174483/discussion-between-charanoglu-and-lovepreet-singh).

Comment: I tried this on a PHP testbed and it worked fine, please see [my example](https://tehplayground.com/8HrN1wOxusXRoqS9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [array_reverse](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php) documentation. Second parameter, *if set to TRUE numeric keys are preserved. Non-numeric keys are not affected by this setting and will always be preserved*.

So try removing `true` as second parameter.

```
$reversed = array_reverse($result);
return $response->withJson($reversed);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not pass `true` in the second argument of `array_reverse`.

Try replacing your code to:

```
$reversed = array_reverse($result, false);
```

Or just:

```
$reversed = array_reverse($result);
```

The second argument is preserving original array keys. The problem with that is that JavaScript will change it's order according to the keys, so the output of the json will be:

```
{"1":{"id":"2644689"},"0":{"id":"2644688"}}
```

And JavaScript will change the order to 0,1.